# Liferay NullPointerException ViewAction

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6.2

could you please help me to debug the following exception I am getting in Liferay Portal?

URL /c/portal/layout

java.lang.NullPointerException
/com.liferay.portlet.assetpublisher.action.ViewAction

```
…che.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getRequestURL (ApplicationHttpRequest.java:490)
…x.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getRequestURL (HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:211)
…x.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getRequestURL (HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:211)
com.liferay.portal.util.HttpImpl.getCompleteURL (HttpImpl.java:382)
com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.HttpUtil.getCompleteURL (HttpUtil.java:102)
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.getCurrentURL (PortalImpl.java:1797)
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.getCurrentURL (PortalUtil.java:472)
com.liferay.portlet.PortletURLUtil.getRefreshURL (PortletURLUtil.java:256)
com.liferay.portlet.PortletURLUtil.getRefreshURL (PortletURLUtil.java:167)
…che.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService (render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1694)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service (HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:731)
…liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include (DirectRequestDispatcher.java:57)
…servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch (ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
…al.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include (ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._doRender (PortletContainerImpl.java:638)
com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.render (PortletContainerImpl.java:135)
…liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.render (SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:141)
…liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.render (RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:126)
…eray.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.render (PortletContainerUtil.java:156)
…ortal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer._render (PortletRenderer.java:125)
…rtal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer.access$4 (PortletRenderer.java:107)
…on.util.PortletRenderer$PortletRendererCallable.doCall (PortletRenderer.java:180)
…on.util.PortletRenderer$PortletRendererCallable.doCall (PortletRenderer.java:1)
…ay.portal.kernel.executor.CopyThreadLocalCallable.call (CopyThreadLocalCallable.java:69)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:262)
…rnel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:682)
…al.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:593)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
```

I am running Liferay Portal Enterprise Edition 6.2.10 EE GA1. Any clue?

Best regards,

Fabrício Sperandio

Comment: You're running EE, so you could also open a support ticket with Liferay. Is there any of your own code involved? If it is, we'll need to see it to help. If it isn't, Stackoverflow is the wrong place to ask. In any case, we need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be able to help

Comment: Olaf is right ..  so far it is just something while trying to render a portlet